# How do the different Neutrino masses come about?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, mass, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

The determination of the Neutrino mass can be roughly divided in three strategies:

The neutrino mass from cosmological observations:
$$m_\nu = \sum_{i} m_i $$

The neutrino mass from the neutrinoless double beta decay:
$$
m_\nu = \lvert \sum_i U_{ei}^2 m_i \rvert
$$

The neutrino mass from the beta-decay kinematic spectrum:
$$
m_\nu = \sqrt{ \sum_i |U_{ei}^2| m_i^2 }
$$

Where $m_i$ are the mass eigenstates of the neutrino(s) and $U_{ei}$ are the entries of the PMNS matrix.

My question is: How do these different formulas come about? Why do they look "so different"?

Comment: Your last formula has inconsistent dimensions.

Comment: forgot a square for the mass, thank you, it is corrected now

Comment: Not enough for an answer , but roughly: In cosmology, you check the gravitational effect of all neutrinos (because they´re assumed to be produced in equal numbers), in $0\nu\beta\beta$ you measure the decay rate (sum of branching ratios), and in $\beta$ spectrum you measure the kinematic effect (involving an electron)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They look different because they're not all the same thing!

The cosmological one is the easiest to understand: it's the *sum* of the 3 neutrino mass eigenstates' eigenvalues.  (Or, as most neutrino physicists would say in casual speech, "the sum of the neutrino masses.").  Incidentally, the relevant constraints usually come from combining numerous astronomical datasets and using a model for dark matter to constrain the mass sum via the impact it'd have on the Cosmic Microwave Background spectrum.  (Depending on who you ask, these limits are either extremely powerful or depend on a lot of model assumptions and are thus pretty shaky.)  These *only* get you the total of the masses; they don't say anything about the *individual* mass states.  (Though once you have them, if you trust these constraints you can combine them from results of neutrino oscillation experiments that measure $\Delta m_{ij}^2$ to work out some info about the individual states.)

The other two cases use electron-flavor neutrinos only (or strictly speaking, in the neutrinoless double beta decay case, the absence of them), and that's what mass you get back.  The relevant quirk about neutrinos here is that the phenomenon of [neutrino mixing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation) makes the flavor states not actually have well-defined masses.  So the observable for the beta-decay case---the difference between the observed endpoint of the tritium spectrum and the upper limit if the neutrino involved had no mass--is actually a mass difference that is split up probabilistically over the mass states that mix into the electron flavor state.  Those probabilities are encoded in the PMNS matrix, which is why it makes an appearance here.  (And why it's a sum only over the 3 $ei$ elements of the matrix and not all 9!).  The second quantity you quoted is usually called the "effective electron (anti)neutrino mass" for that reason.

The difference between the latter two also comes down to the difference in the observable.  The $0\nu \beta\beta$ process (where the neutrino(s) are virtual particles and are never emitted) has a couple of different quantum mechanical amplitudes that can interfere, vs the tritium decay endpoint process where a real neutrino is emitted.  (If you've ever taken any quantum mechanics it's the difference between a coherent and incoherent sum over the relevant amplitudes.). This quantity only means anything--and can only be measured to be nonzero--if neutrinos are [Majorana particles](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_fermion), so it's usually called the "effective Majorana mass" (in analogy with the previous one).